# single sign on for ASP.net and java application

Tags: java, .net, single-sign-on

I have 2 application one in ASP.net and 2nd in Java. I need to create login for the applications.

If user is logged into one application he need to be automatically logged into 2nd application too. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find an SSO solution that can be integrated with your ASP.net application, presenting you with plugins and extensions that can interact with that SSO server. There are many options available for you to evaluate, such as Shibboleth, ADFS, CAS, etc. The specifics of the SSO server deployment as well as the integration with each application depends on your choice of deployment and likely is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: but i have one application in ASP.net and 2nd one in JAVA. is there any good sso solution which i can integrate with both java and asp.net

Comment: Any of the ones I mentioned above do the job, especially CAS and/or Shibboleth.